# Comparator doesn't work with Binary Tree

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, comparator

I have this thing

**Comparator.java**

```
public interface Comparator<T> {
    public int compareTo(int num);
}
```

**valueComparator.java**

```
public class valueComparator implements Comparator<Tree.Node> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Tree.Node obj, int number) {
        if (obj.getDataNumber() == number) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (obj.getDataNumber() < number) {
            return -1;
        }
        else return 1;
    }
}
```

**Tree.java**

```
public class Tree {
    public Node root;

    Tree() {
    }

    public static class Node {

        Node(int number, String str, boolean flag) {
            dataNumber = number;
            dataText = str;
            dataBool = flag;
        }

        public int getDataNumber() {
            return this.dataNumber;
        }

        public String getDataText() {
            return this.dataText;
        }

        public boolean getDataBool() {
            return this.dataBool;
        }

        public void setDataText(String text) {
            this.dataText = text;
        }

        public void isDataBool(boolean flag) {
            this.dataBool = flag;
        }

        Node left;
        Node right;
        private int dataNumber;
        private String dataText;
        private boolean dataBool;

    }

    public void binaryTree() {
        root = null;
    }

    public boolean search(int number) {
        return search(root, number);
    }

    valueComparator comp = new valueComparator();

    private boolean search(Node node, int number) {
        if (node == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (comp.compareTo(node, number) == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        if (comp.compareTo(node, number) == -1) {
            return search(node.left, number);
        }
        else {
            return search(node.right, number);
        }
    }  

    public void insertLeaf(int number, String str, boolean flag) {
    root = insertLeaf(root, number, str, flag);
    }
    private Node insertLeaf(Node node, int number, String str, boolean flag) {
        if (node == null) {
            node = new Node(number, str, flag);
        } else {
            if (number < node.dataNumber) {
                node.left = insertLeaf(node.left, number, str, flag);
            }
            else if (number > node.dataNumber) {
                node.right = insertLeaf(node.right, number, str, flag);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("The element is already in the tree.");
            }
        }
        return node;
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Tree binTree = new Tree();
        binTree.binaryTree();
        binTree.insertLeaf(5, "text2", true);
        binTree.insertLeaf(4, "text4", false);
        binTree.insertLeaf(1, "text1", true);
        binTree.insertLeaf(3, "text3", true);
        binTree.insertLeaf(2, "text5", false);
        System.out.println("Element 3 found: " + binTree.search(3));
    // Element 3 found: false
    }
}
```

I am supposed to do the search with a comparator, but I fail to understand the logic. The `compareTo` method works for itself but it stucks at the recursive call of search. After the first pass, if the return of compareTo is not = 0, then it enters with `null` and breaks out of recursion and returns false. Meaning if I set the first element of the tree to be '3', the search(3) will return true, but if it's different than 3 - false and won't even look for it in the tree.

Comment: Could you add a tag for the programming language you're using?

Comment: Please post real code, that compiles. Your Comparator can't compile.

Comment: Sorry.. It's just my first time posting here :D

Comment: The code you have shown us doesn't compile.  It's odd, anyway.  You've defined an interface as a generic type, but then none of the method signatures you declare use that generic type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you **insert** a number you compare it directly to the nodes' values and if the number is less than the value stored in the current node, you follow the `left` pointer.

However when you **search** for a number, you use a comparator, which compares the node's value to the number given (note the opposite order!) and if the number is less than the value in the current node, you follow a `right` link.

Use either direct comparision or a comparator, as you wish – but use the same method everywhere.

Comment: You, my friend, deserve a beer! Thank you!